# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am running a CNN that check for images but does not classify. In fact, the output layer is a dense layer that have as argument the size of the images in the labels in 1d.

As shown below in the code, I am using model.fit_generator() instead of model.fit and when it comes to start training the model the following error comes up:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 
  'builtin_function_or_method'

I am not really getting why this is happening. 
Here attached is the summary of the model:

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 877, 32)       544

---

activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 26, 877, 32)       0

---

max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 13, 438, 32)       0

---

conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 437, 16)       2064

---

activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 12, 437, 16)       0

---

max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 218, 16)        0

---

conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 5, 217, 8)         520

---

activation_7 (Activation)    (None, 5, 217, 8)         0

---

max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 108, 8)         0

---

activation_8 (Activation)    (None, 2, 108, 8)         0

---

flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 1728)              0

---

dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1728)              0

---

dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 19316)             33397364

=================================================================

Total params: 33,400,492
Trainable params: 33,400,492
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Any suggestions ? 
Thanks a lot in advance!

I have already looked up many of the online forums/websites but I don't seem to find one that suits my case.

```
def generator(data_arr, batch_size = 10):

num = len(data_arr) 

if num % batch_size != 0 : 
    num = int(num/batch_size)

# Loop forever so the generator never terminates
while True: 

    for offset in range(0, num, batch_size):

        batch_samples = (data_arr[offset:offset+batch_size])

        samples = []
        labels = []

        for batch_sample in batch_samples:

            samples.append(batch_sample[0])
            labels.append((np.array(batch_sample[1].flatten)).transpose())

        X_ = np.array(samples)
        Y_ = np.array(labels)

        X_ = X_[:, :, :, newaxis]

        print(X_.shape)
        print(Y_.shape)

        yield (X_, Y_)

# compile and train the model using the generator function
train_generator = generator(training_data, batch_size = 10)
validation_generator = generator(val_data, batch_size = 10)

run_opts = tf.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom = True)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), input_shape = (55, 1756, 
1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(8, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature 
vectors
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(19316))

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics = ['accuracy'],
              options = run_opts)

model.summary()

batch_size = 20
nb_epoch = 6

model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                    steps_per_epoch = len(training_data) ,
                    epochs = nb_epoch,
                    validation_data = validation_generator,
                    validation_steps = len(val_data))
```

Comment: Which line does the error come up?

Comment: Youre probably forgetting a couple of () and passing a function pointer rather than calling the function and passing the result.

Comment: Just eyeballing it - but I'm not familiar with the libraries in question - I suspect this line: `np.array(batch_sample[1].flatten))`. Should that be `.flatten()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is this line

```py
labels.append((np.array(batch_sample[1].flatten)).transpose())
```

which should rather be

```py
labels.append((np.array(batch_sample[1].flatten())).transpose())
```